# Django Admin Page - links to apps are inactive after setting DEBUG to false

Tags: django, django-admin, mod-wsgi

I am in the process of deploying a django site using Apache and mod_wsgi.

Everything was working fine, so I disabled DEBUG in my settings.py.

Now most things still work (i.e. static content is served correctly through my settings, etc).

The problem is that on the admin page, my installed apps show up, but are not clickable... So I cannot get it to create posts or upload photos or whatever else all my apps were built to do.

Setting debug back to True immediately fixes the problem, but I have no error output in either my error log or my access log that points me as to where this problem is occurring. My logging is set up in my httpd.conf as follows:

```
ErrorLog /srv/www/sitename.com/logs/error.log
CustomLog /srv/www/sitename.com/logs/access.log combined
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked permissions? Or used browser debuging to see if there is any css/js that is not loading?

Comment: I have already dealt with some permission issues, so I don't believe that is the problem. There was difficulty accessing the sqlite db, so now the whole dir belongs to www-data. And it appears as if all css/js is loading just fine.